# Dynamodb query an attribute in all map elements

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a JSON structure like this

```
{
  'partition_key': '1',
  'map': {
    'a': {'x': 'value1', 'y': 'value4'},
    'b': {'x': 'value2', 'y': 'value5'},
    'c': {'x': 'value3', 'y': 'value6'},
  }
}
```

I want to query all `x` values and but let's say that the `y` values are large and I would rather not send the entire JSON. Isn't there something like a [JQ](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) style query language? Something like a wildcard (in Python/boto3)

```
    table.get_item(
        Key={'partition_key': '1'},
        ProjectionExpression="map.*.x"
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

No its not possible in DynamoDB. If the values are large, you would be better splitting them into smaller items, and that way you can get more fine-grained with your query expression.

Comment: The values are already split into very small items. Those are basically boolean lists with millions of entries. Granularity is not the issue.

Comment: But you save nothing by only returning part of the map?

Comment: I want to have the `x` from all entries. I suppose I could create separate tables for x and y. But then I also need to keep track of consistency of the data. I guess I'm better off using SQL. Which is strange because it's such a simple and essential feature to have some kind of JQ-like query language. There is no reason why NoSQL wouldn't be able to support it :/ . Thank you for help anyway.